# TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int() CodeWars: Count of positives / sum of negatives

Tags: python

I've tried searching google and this website for an explanation I understand, but have come up short. I'm attempting a question on CodeWars: Count of positives / sum of negatives.

The question is:

Given an array of integers.

Return an array, where the first element is the count of positives numbers and the second element is sum of negative numbers.

If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array.

And the testing variables are:

```
Test.describe("Basic tests")
Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]),[10,-65])
Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14]),[8,-50])
Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([1]),[1,0])
Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([-1]),[0,-1])
Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]),[0,0])
Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([]),[])
```

So the code I wrote is:

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return []
    positive_counter = 0
    negative_sum = 0
    for x in arr:
        if x > 0:
            positive_counter += 1 
        elif x < 0:
            negative_sum += x  
    return (postive_counter, negative_sum)
```

When I attempt the submission on the website I'm given:

Basic tests
✘ (10, -65) should equal [10, -65]

And when I attempt it in a Python interpreter I get: 
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()

So I know something is wrong in the first test.assert_equals list where there is a second element in the list, but I've not been successful in how to rectify the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: looks like you are returning a `tuple` (in `()` round brackets) but checking it against a `list` (with `[]` square brackets)  So if you stay consistent with which data type you use it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a list i.e.

```
return [postive_counter, negative_sum]
```